# How to fix error message in tcl script having command [exec bjobs] when no jobs are running?

Tags: unix, tcl, lsf

when I am running a Tcl script that contains the following lines:

```
set V [exec bjobs ]
puts "bjobs= ${V}"
```

When jobs are present it's working properly but, no jobs are running it is showing an error like this:

```
No unfinished job found
    while executing
"exec bjobs "
    invoked from within
"set V [exec bjobs ]"
```

How to avoid this error? Please let me know how to avoid this kind of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if {[catch {exec bjobs} result]} {
    puts "bjobs have some issues. Reason : $result"
} else {
    puts "bjobs executed successfully. Result : $result"
}
```

**Reference :**  [catch](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/catch.htm)

Comment: This code suppress error message, along with that I want to suppress the  "No unfinished job found" message or redirect it to variable. can u please help me in doing this

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like the `bjobs` program has a non-zero exit code in this case. The `exec` manual page includes this example in a subsection `WORKING WITH NON-ZERO RESULTS`:

> To execute a program that can return a non-zero result, you should wrap
> the call to **exec** in **catch** and check  the  contents  of  the  **-errorcode**
> return option if you have an error:
>
> ```
>       set status 0
>       if {[catch {exec grep foo bar.txt} results options]} {
>           set details [dict get $options -errorcode]
>           if {[lindex $details 0] eq "CHILDSTATUS"} {
>               set status [lindex $details 2]
>           } else {
>               # Some other error; regenerate it to let caller handle
>               return -options $options -level 0 $results
>           }
>       }
> ```
>
> This  is  more  easily  written using the **try** command, as that makes it
> simpler to trap specific types of errors. This is done using code  like
> this:
>
> ```
>       try {
>           set results [exec grep foo bar.txt]
>           set status 0
>       } trap CHILDSTATUS {results options} {
>           set status [lindex [dict get $options -errorcode] 2]
>       }
> ```

I think you could write this as:

```
try {
    set V [exec bjobs ]
} trap CHILDSTATUS {message} {
    # Not sure how you want to handle the case where there's nothing...
    set V $message
}
puts "bjobs= ${V}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Note carefully in the [`exec` man
page](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm):

> If any of the commands in the pipeline exit abnormally or are killed or
> suspended, then `exec` will return an error [...]
> If any of the commands
> writes to its standard error file and that standard error is not
> redirected and
> `-ignorestderr` is not specified, then `exec` will return an
> error.

So if `bjobs` returns non-zero or prints to stderr when there are no jobs, exec needs catch or try as Donal writes.